# Match O-linker Error , clang error iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang, mach-o

I recently created a new project and copied resources from another project, But when i compiled, it generated one error,
I checked twice resources are ok, but its showing Mach-O Linker error, I tried other answers, but nothing is working for me..

> Ld
>   /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app/MyProject
>   normal x86_64
>
> ```
> cd "/Users/iOSDEV/Developer/untitled folder/MyProject"
>
> export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.3
>
> export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
> ```
>
> -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/iOSDEV/Developer/untitled\ folder/MyProject -filelist /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyProject.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.3 -framework Accounts -framework JudoPay -framework QuartzCore -framework
>   Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security
>   -framework CoreTelephony -framework UIKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyProject_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app/MyProject
>
> duplicate symbol _delegate in:
>
> ```
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuViewController.o
>
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PlaceOrderViewController-B3C1DC5507CD786B.o
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _delegate in:
>
> ```
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuViewController.o
>
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LeftSideViewController.o
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _delegate in:
>
> ```
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuViewController.o
>
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ReOrderViewController.o
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _delegate in:
>
> ```
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuViewController.o
>
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AddToCart.o
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _delegate in:
>
> ```
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuViewController.o
>
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyOrdersViewController.o
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _delegate in:
>
> ```
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuViewController.o
>
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Cart.o
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _delegate in:
>
> ```
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuViewController.o
>
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuDetailViewController.o
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _delegate in:
>
> ```
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuViewController.o
>
> /Users/iOSDEV/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ProductDetailViewController-86CA1752309DD871.o
> ```
>
> ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: How did you copy everything over?

Comment: I used a folder named view controllers, in which i had nibs and view controllers .h and .m files, I dragged that folder to my new created project..

Comment: never pasted anything again.